# deleting specific node in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I need to delete specific employee node and also its child node based on the value of id.
For example, here I need to delete employee tag with id="2".

```
<company>
    <employee>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>sa</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>ssa</name>
    </employee>
</company>
```

Comment: What version of .net are you using, changes the answer quite a bit

Comment: i am using framework 2.0

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you have loaded that into an `XmlDocument` named `doc`:

```
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("/company/employee[id=2]");
if(el != null) { el.ParentNode.RemoveChild(el); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the el.ParentNode.RemoveChild(el) construction - was going round in circles trying to reference the node I'd found with respect to the document in order to remove it!

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 XmlNode nodeToDelete = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/XMLFileName[@ID="+nodeId+"]");
            if (nodeToDelete != null)
            {
                nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
            }
            xmlDoc.Save("XMLFileName.xml")
```