# How To Remove Last Node In XML? C#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I am trying to remove the last  node from an XML file, but cannot find any good answers for doing this. Here is my code:

```
XmlReader x = XmlReader.Create(this.PathToSpecialFolder + @"\" + Application.CompanyName + @"\" + Application.ProductName + @"\Recent.xml");

int c = 0;
while (x.Read())
{
    if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "Path") 
    {
        c++;
        if (c <= 10)
        {
            MenuItem m = new MenuItem() { Header = x.ReadInnerXml() };
            m.Click += delegate
            {
            };
            openRecentMenuItem.Items.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
x.Close();
```

My XML node structure is as follows...

```
<RecentFiles>
    <File>
        <Path>Text Path</Path>
    </File>
</RecentFiles>
```

In my situation, there will be ten nodes maximum, and each time a new one is added, the last must be removed.

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlReader? I'd use LINQ to XML, which makes this pretty trivial...

Comment: Provided you gave an example, I would consider it; this, however, doesn't answer my question.

Comment: And that's why I added it as a comment rather than an answer, of course. Comments are usually used to ask for clarification of the question. So, to ask for *more* clarification - is it just the `Path` element that you want to remove? Or the `File` element? It would help if you could give some sample "input and expected output" examples, particularly with multiple elements.

Comment: Remove the last node (child) of `RecentFiles` or `File`?

Comment: @AlexYoung: Edit this into your question, not into comments.

Comment: I think what you want is a Queue.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  Note that nodes can exist in two containers simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in the original post: I am trying to remove the last <File> node each time a new <File> node is added to the beginning. So I am assuming I have to know how to select this last node. In jQuery, it's a piece of cake: $("#blah:last-child").remove(). Is C# this straightforward?

Comment: And what is your definition of "last node"? Where do you add the new node (front or back)?

Comment: The last node would be the last as it appears in the text file and the first vice versa. I suppose either could be the front or the back depending on how you look at it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting specific node in xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229330/deleting-specific-node-in-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/RecentFiles/File");
nodes[nodes.Count].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[nodes.Count]);
doc.Save(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var lastFile = doc.Descendants("File").LastOrDefault();
if (lastFile != null)
{
    lastFile.Remove();
}
// Now save doc or whatever you want to do with it...
```