# Target specific Xml Node in c#

Tags: c#, xml

As I said in the Title: I'm trying to delete a specific XML node(in c#).

so I researched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229330/deleting-specific-node-in-xml):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode nodeToDelete = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/XMLFileName[@ID="+nodeId+"]");
        if (nodeToDelete != null)
        {
            nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
        }
        xmlDoc.Save("XMLFileName.xml")
```

I understand here that he's targeting a specific node ( in this case `"[@ID ="+nodeId+`)

Ok, my question is can I do the same just in the opposite way, by that I mean if its not `nodeId` then delete it (just like the "!="-Operator in C#).

Comment: The Autor of this Code (See Link)

Comment: That link wasn't there a moment ago, was it? Anyway, you want to learn about [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath), that's the language used in the `/root/XMLFileName[@ID=xyz]` expression. As such, your question is unrelated to deleting a node.

Comment: yes there is a != operator. Why don't you try and post what's wrong with your result.

Comment: I'm sure it was :) , oh thanks for giving me an answer. :) have a great Day :)

Comment: @artragis but if i set the "!=" operater i will get not only One Node ... or? ( I'm sorry i never did something in Xml)

Comment: @Gentle: Please check the [docs for `SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The method you use is quite transparent **`selectSINGLEnode`**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the code you posted uses `SelectSingleNode` which will allways return only one node.

First thing to do : using `SelectNodes` whose doc is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

THe result would be :

```
List<XmlNode> nodes =  new List<XmlNode>(
    xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//root/XMLFileName[@ID!="+nodeId+"]")
        .Cast<XmlNode>());//execute the query and put it into a list
// as my list is strongly typed, I **must** use cast method
// thanks to this list, I can modify the document without changing the 
// collection that foreach is traversing
foreach(var nodeToDelete in nodes){
    if (nodeToDelete != null)
    {
        nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
    }

}
xmlDoc.Save("XMLFileName.xml")
```

You can also use a linq query as you are in C# as explained [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564).

Comment: Thanks :) it helpes me out but i have problems to understand everything :/ still thank u for helping me out :)

Comment: what do you not understand?

Comment: It will not be disturbance as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Thanks for being such kind :) , So i get the error message That my List has some invalid arguments... what could it possibly be?

Comment: I made a little mistake. I correct it with some explanation.

Comment: at : new List<XmlNode>(doc.SelectNodes(filepath + "[@ID!=1").Cast<XmlNode>())... it throws System.Xml.XPath.XPathException... it may be again a silly question...