# Trying to delete an XML Node based on attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to delete one record from the XML based on some attribute value. My XML structure is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
  <User>
    <UserId>12345</UserId>
    <FirstName>abcd</FirstName>
    <LastName>efgh</LastName>
    <Email>Hello@hello.com</Email>
    <IsAdmin>No</IsAdmin>
  </User>
  <User>
    <UserId>67890</UserId>
    <FirstName>ijklm</FirstName>
    <LastName>nopqr</LastName>
    <Email>world@world.com</Email>
    <IsAdmin>No</IsAdmin>
  </User>
  <User>
    <UserId>12678</UserId>
    <FirstName>stuv</FirstName>
    <LastName>wxyz</LastName>
    <Email>foo@bar.com</Email>
    <IsAdmin>Yes</IsAdmin>
  </User>
</Users>
```

E.g if attribute value is 12345 it should delete the below record from the XML.

```
<User>
        <UserId>12345</UserId>
        <FirstName>abcd</FirstName>
        <LastName>efgh</LastName>
        <Email>Hello@hello.com</Email>
        <IsAdmin>No</IsAdmin>
      </User>
```

I tried below code but I am not able to delete anything from the XML.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/XML/users.xml");
                XElement xEle = XElement.Load(path);
                var qry = from element in xEle.Descendants()
                          where (string)element.Attribute("UserId").Value == "12345"
                          select element;
                if (qry.Count() > 0)
                    qry.First().Remove();
                xEle.Save(path);
```

I am unable to figure this out. Any help with be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229330/deleting-specific-node-in-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<UserId>12345</UserId>` is a nested sub-element of `<User>`, not an attribute.  See [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element) to see the difference.

Thus you need to do:

```
        var userId = "12345";

        var qry = from element in xEle.Descendants("User")
                  where (string)element.Element("UserId") == userId
                  select element;
        var first = qry.FirstOrDefault();
        if (first != null)
            first.Remove();
```

Incidentally, by calling both `Count()` and `First()`, you are evaluating your query twice.  [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the first matching element, or `null` if the enumerable is empty, and is thus more efficient.

Comment: Thank a lot for the help. Really appreciate this. Working just fine now :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `qry.Take(1).Remove()` to remove the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

UserId is not attribute in the XML. Its an element

```
XElement xEle = XElement.Load("input.xml");
        var qry = from element in xEle.Descendants()
                  where (string)element.Element("UserId") == "12345"
                  select element;
        if (qry.Count() > 0)
            qry.First().Remove();
        xEle.Save("input.xml");
```

And in your snippet you are comparing 12345 int with string type